# How to use Term Query for nested objects in spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

My Document is like:

```
class Foo{
 private Integer idDl;
 private String Name;
 private String Add;
 @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
 private List< Bar> Bar;
 }
 
 class Bar{
 private String barId;
 private List<String> barData
 }
```

and `Foo` sample response data is like:

```
{
    "idDl": 123,
    "Name": "ABCD",
    "Add": "FL",
    "Bar": [
        {
            "barId": "A456B",
            "barData": [
                "Bar1",
                "Bar2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "barId": "A985D",
            "barData": [
                "Bar4",
                "Bar5"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return all `Foo`objects where `Bar.barId` is matching. I am using `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` provided by spring-data-elasticsearch as:

```
String[] includeFields = new String[]{"idDl", "Name"};
String[] excludeFields = new String[]{"Add"}; // to exclude Add field of Foo
Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(termQuery("Bar.barId", "A456B"))
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(includeFields, excludeFields))
            .build();
return elasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForList( searchQuery, Foo.class);
```

We have also tried using `nestedQuery` as follows:

```
 SearchQuery  searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(nestedQuery("Bar",
                 boolQuery().must(termQuery("Bar.barId", "A456B")), ScoreMode.Max))
                .withIndices(indices)
                .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(includeFields, excludeFields))
                .build();
         return elasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, Foo.class);
```

But getting exception as:

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.7.jar:6.8.7]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2053) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.7.jar:6.8.7]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2030) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.7.jar:6.8.7]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1777) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.7.jar:6.8.7]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.7.jar:6.8.7]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1696) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.7.jar:6.8.7]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:1092) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.7.jar:6.8.7]
```

I am using `termQuery` as in the first snippet but i ain't getting response for it and but instead if i use `matchQuery("Bar.barId", "A456B")` I am getting the response. We just want to check query performance using `termQuery` and `matchQuery`.How to fetch the data using `termQuery` ?

P.S:  we are using `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` 2.2.6.RELEASE in our `spring-boot` project.

Comment: Check whether cluster is up?

Comment: @gibbs, It's up. We're getting results for other match queries.

Comment: What is the mapping of `Bar.barid`?

Comment: it is of type text

Comment: What is the analyser used on that?

Comment: We haven't specified any separate analyzer, I guess it is using default one or whichever spring-data-elasticsearch uses by default. As posted above, it is simple mapping having text and nested field.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any analyser. So default one is used `standard analyzer`

> Unlike full-text queries, term-level queries do not analyze search terms. Instead, term-level queries match the exact terms stored in a field.

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html)

Term query do not analyse which means it looks for `A456B` but index contains `a456b` due to the behaviour of [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which contains `lowercase tokenizer`

Whereas `match` query is a `full text search` query which does the analyser on index time and search time. So search time a456b`matches the words in the index`a3456b`.

Comment: Thanks @Gibbs. Would you please suggest how to make this term query work? we just wanted to check the performance of term vs match queries. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Give a try on `Bar.barId.keyword` in terms query

Comment: Can you add your mapping by executing `http://host:port/indexName/_mapping`

Comment: that's what we did at the start.

Comment: we have already added mapping by hitting the service you mentioned

Comment: If you add the response of it, we can check further. No, This is a GET request to see whether you have keyword version of it

Answer (score 1):

We have the similar requirements and solved using this snippet, I've tried to covert it, according to your requirement. Code is pretty straight forward, let me know if you need further clarification.

```
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = boolQuery();
    BoolQueryBuilder nestedBoolQueryBuilder = boolQuery().must(boolQuery()
                    .should(termQuery("Bar.barId", barId.toLowerCase()))).minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
    QueryBuilder nestedQueryBuilder = nestedQuery("Bar", nestedBoolQueryBuilder);
    boolQueryBuilder = boolQueryBuilder.must(nestedQueryBuilder);
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
            .withPageable(pageable)
            .build();
```